# R: Regex to match more than one pipe occurrence

Tags: r

I have a dataset in which I paste values in a dplyr chain and collapse with the pipe character (e.g. " | ").  If any of the values in the dataset are blank, I just get recurring pipe characters in the pasted list.

Some of the values look like this, for example:

```
badstring = "| | | | | | GHOULSBY,SCROGGINS | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | CAT,JOHNSON | | | | | | | | | | | | BURGLAR,PALA | | | | | | | | |"
```

I want to match all the pipes that occur more than once and delete them, so that just the names appear like so:

```
correctstring = "| GHOULSBY,SCROGGINS | CAT,JOHNSON | |BURGLAR,PALA |"
```

I tried the following, but to no avail:

```
mutate(names = gsub('[\\|]{2,}', '', name_list))
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to remove the blank values before creating the string?

Comment: The blank values are simply NAs in my dataset.  In the dplyr command I'm using paste with collapse ("|"), and there doesn't seem to be any ways for paste to ignore NAs outright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty in this question is in formulating a regex which can selectively remove every pipe, except the ones we want to remain as actual separators between terms.  We can match on the following pattern:

```
\|\s+(?=\|)
```

and then replace just empty string.  This pattern will remove any pipe (and any following whitespace) so long as what follows is another pipe.  A removal would *not* occur when a pipe is followed by an actual term, or when it is followed by the end of the string.

```
badstring = "| | | | | | GHOULSBY,SCROGGINS | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | CAT,JOHNSON | | | | | | | | | | | | BURGLAR,PALA | | | | | | | | |"

result <- gsub("\\|\\s+(?=\\|)", "", badstring, perl=TRUE)
result

[1] "| GHOULSBY,SCROGGINS | CAT,JOHNSON | BURGLAR,PALA |"
```

### Demo

**Edit:**

If you expect to have inputs like `| | |` which are devoid of any terms, and you would expect empty string as the output, then my solution would fail.  I don't see an obvious way to modify the above regex, but you can handle this case with one more call to `sub`:

```
result <- sub("^\\|$", "", result)
```

We also might be able to modify the original pattern to use an alternation covering all cases:

```
result <- gsub("\\|\\s+(?=\\|)|(?:^\\|$)", "", badstring, perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: Fantastic work.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but if the string is badstring = "| | |", won't that reduce to just a single pipe?  How would we eliminate that single leading pipe?  e.g.

```badstring = "| | |"
result <- gsub("\\|\\s+(?=\\|)", "", badstring, perl=TRUE)```

Comment: I don't see an obvious way to fix this case.  But, do you really ever expect to have no terms at all?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's quite common in my dataset.  Your second solution works perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: See my latest update.  I think you might be able to use a single call to `sub` which uses an alternation to cover both cases.

Comment: Wow, insanely clever.  Thank you so much